# Resizing Render Target Direct2D after WM_SIZE

Tags: direct2d

Quick question guys... I am currently working with Directx3D and 2D and I was wondering if I have to recreate the render target when the Windows is resized or does Direct2D automatically detects this, since it's bound to the DXGISurface(back-buffer of the swapchain) when I created it.

Here is the code that I used to bind the render targets together:

```
ComPtr<IDXGISurface1> dxgibackBuffer;
hr = m_pDxSwapchain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgibackBuffer));

D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties = D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
    D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW,
    D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
    96.0f,
    96.0f);
hr = m_pD2DContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(dxgibackBuffer.Get(), &bitmapProperties, &m_pD2DTargetBitmap);

// last step
m_pD2DContext->SetTarget(m_pD2DTargetBitmap.Get());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Care_and_Feeding_of_the_Swap_Chain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Care_and_Feeding_of_the_Swap_Chain) and [Handling_Window_Resizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Handling_Window_Resizing)

Quote1: 
Naturally, the application's best route is to respond to `WM_SIZE`, and call [IDXGISwapChain::ResizeBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the size contained in the message's parameters.

Quote2:
Before you call `ResizeBuffers`, you must release all outstanding references to the swap chain's buffers. The object that typically holds a reference to a swap chain's buffer is a render-target-view.